# HTTP Status 404 occur when load index or first page

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

Am new in Spring MVC. i developing my first project. if i run my project got an error HTTP Status 404. there is no deployment error

my web.xml is shown below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

   <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>

</web-app>
```

and my dispatcher servlet

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!-- was: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> -->
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd ">

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="view/index" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.innovaturelabs.multicast.controller" use-default-filters="false">
        <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" />
    </context:component-scan>
    <bean id="viewResolver"
         class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
         p:prefix="/WEB-INF/"
         p:suffix=".html">

    </bean>
</beans>
```

and application servlet is

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!-- was: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> -->
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd">

    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
          class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
          p:location="/WEB-INF/Properties/Database.properties" />

    <util:properties id="hibernateProperties" location="/WEB-INF/Properties/Hibernate.properties" />

    <bean id="dataSource"
          class="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource"
          p:driverClassName="${database.driver}"
          p:url="${database.url}"
          p:username="${database.user}"
          p:password="${database.password}"
          p:testWhileIdle="true"
          p:validationQuery="SELECT 1" />


    <bean id="UserDao" class="com.innovaturelabs.multicast.dao.UserDao" />
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean"
      p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
      p:packagesToScan="com.innovaturelabs.spring.web.entity"
      p:hibernateProperties-ref="hibernateProperties" />

</beans>
```

Comment: 404 is a  client error - "i couldn't find that page" what context are you running on what url are you accessing? what does the access log say?

Comment: the html file placed WEB-INF/view/index.html.      tomcat log not produce  any error messages

Comment: What is the name of your JAR file and can you post your Maven POM?

Comment: what url are you using to try to access it? http://localhost:8080/ ??

Comment: http://localhost:8084/Multicast/

Comment: and what server are you running? tomcat? glassfish? weblogic?

Comment: am using tomcat server

Comment: @AjmalMuhammad I see that you're using spring mvc. Can you show us the controller that is mapped to `/` address?

Comment: redirect using this method. placed on dispatcher controller <mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="view/index" />

Comment: You have any exception when you deploy your war?

Comment: no deploy error and exception

Comment: do you see that your war is deployed?

Comment: @AjmalMuhammad And how do you call your application?

Comment: run by using netbeans ide

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89989/discussion-between-ajmal-muhammad-and-jens).

Answer (score -1):

As far as you mapped dispatcher servlet at "/" all requests are getting by it.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.innovaturelabs.multicast.controller" use-default-filters="false">
    <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" />
</context:component-scan>
```

Did you write your controller in this package?

Something like:

```
package com.innovaturelabs.multicast.controller;

@Controller
public class  Controler() {
  @RequestMapping("/")
  public String index() {
    return "index";
  }
}
```

Another thing is that u should use jsp files with `InternalResourceViewResolver` instead of html.

```
   <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
         p:prefix="/WEB-INF/"
         p:suffix=".jsp">
    </bean>
```

Html files should be in static folder and mapped by mvc:resource tag

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**"
               location="/resources/html/"
```

I am new to spring as well. Hope i could help.

Comment: ur answer is not sufficient